# react native import packages showing error in expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I try to create a credit card details input using [this link](https://snack.expo.io/rJ7q6PhSb)

Then I run through expo then I got this error

> Unable to resolve react-native-credit-card-input" from ".//App.js"

but try this code also in the terminal by my app location is desktop/myapp/card

```
npm i --save react-native-credit-card-input
```

How can I fix this error

Comment: try command _react-native link_ after you install the package.

Comment: thz but where can i install ?  in desktop i run those  command